# When will a startscript of a parent image being executed in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The parentimage in my Dockerfile has a startscript (ENTRYPOINT).
And in my Dockerfile i have a ENTRYPOINT two.

My Question is now: Which startscript is beeing executed at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for ENTRYPOINT state: Only the last ENTRYPOINT instruction in the Dockerfile will have an effect.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Answer (score 0):

if your scenario consist of running multiple service , then you can use supervisord service to run service in sequence
http://blog.kunicki.org/blog/2016/02/12/multiple-entrypoints-in-docker/